# out-of-memory error. How to locate? How to solve?

Tags: memory-management, fortran

Am trying to run a Fortran code on a Cray.  It works fine when compiled under gnu or intel.  When I try to run it as compiled under Cray Fortran, it dies with an "OOM killer" error.  I have no idea where in the code the error is coming from.  I have no idea why the Cray compiler would have problems when the other compilers do not.  Most of all, I have tried various compiler switches and (un-)activating "huge pages", all to no avail.  How can I locate this error?  Better still, how can I solve it?

Comment: I fear the answer is to make a [mcve] by a possibly hard work of enabling and disabling various parts of the code. It can take a long time.

Comment: Do begin with, is this FORTRAN (as in 77) or Fortran (as is known as FortrAda)? This would determine if the failure is the result of dynamic memory. Also, is the only difference the compiler? You are running this on the same system?

Comment: @user3344003  This is Fortran 90 (or later) and I am running on the same system.  Only the compiler is changed.  Thanks.

Comment: Does it die right at the beginning?

Comment: @user3344003  No.  Takes a while.  I am trying to find out exactly where right now.

Comment: @user3344003  If you're interested, I solved the problem and posted an answer.  There are still things going on I don't understand, if you want to weigh in.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone's interested, I took Vladimir F's advice and started disabling parts of the code to find the problem.  I was fortunate that it didn't take all that long.  There is a section of the code where I have allocatable integer arrays that I work on in a loop.  It is not clear what the size of the arrays has to be at runtime.  So I allocated them to some size and then as the loop iterates, if they grow beyond their bounds, I reallocate them, increasing the size by some increment, 100 in my default case.  I don't know the internals of how a Cray compiler works, but this resulted in too many re-allocations for it to handle, and it reported the error as an out-of-memory error.  I increased the increment to 500 integers, and that solved the problem.  If anyone wants to shed light on what is really going on, I would be more than happy to hear about it.

Comment: You could check the address of those arrays, whether the allocator is re-using the released memory or always claiming a fresh piece. You can certainly report this to your cluster support or to your local Cray representative.

Comment: It's probably the Fortran run time library that caused the problem then. Fragmenting the heap so that it cannot reallocate.

Comment: Isn't it better to increase the size of the array by multiplying by some factor (say, 1.5 or 2.0) rather than increasing it by a constant length (100 or 500)? The latter method needs much more reallocation if the final size is very large.